# I want to move,animate and rotate object at the same time

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, move

Here is the code:

```
ball = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Ball.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 52, 52)];
        ball.position = ccp(300, 300);
        ball.tag = 1;
        [self addChild:ball z:-1];

        // Create ball body 
        //b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
        ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
        ballBodyDef.position.Set(100/PTM_RATIO, 300/PTM_RATIO);
        ballBodyDef.userData = ball;
        b2Body * ballBody = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

        // Create circle shape
        b2CircleShape circle;
        circle.m_radius = 20.0/PTM_RATIO;

        // Create shape definition and add to body
        b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
        ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
        ballShapeDef.density = -2.5f;
        ballShapeDef.friction = 0.01f;
        ballShapeDef.restitution = 1.0f;
        _ballFixture = ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);

        b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(5, 7);
        ballBody->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, ballBodyDef.position);
```

I want to rotate,animate and move ball but i am confused,How to apply all things at the same time!?

Comment: How do you want to rotate, animate and move the object?  You could just apply each of the transformations sequentially for example; or compose them together to create one big transformation.  Without being more specific, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: I have done this by applying animation on box2d object....@Mikola..Thax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Spawn action to play many action at the same time.
id spawAction = [CCSpawn actions:moveAction, rotateAction, nil];
[aSprite runAction:spawAction];

Answer (score 1):

For example, how to apply box2d position and rotation to CCNode,

```
// Position
b2Vec2 b2pos = ballBody->GetPosition();
CGPoint position = ccpMult(CGPointMake(b2pos.x, b2pos.y), PTM_RATIO);
ball.position = position;

// Rotation
float angle = ballBody->GetAngle();
ball.rotation = -(CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle));
```

By the way, [CCBox2D](https://github.com/axcho/CCBox2D) is helpful with cocos2d and Box2d.